# How to use a mysql query with aliases(AS) in ireport?

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports

Hey i'm designing a report for my project using ireport.it's like this,

```
              **DAILY REPORT** 

               2016-02-01

               Items sold : "Sold item count of the day"

               ..........
```

and this is my table

```
invoice_no | main_category | subcategory | ......
-----------+---------------+-------------+-------
     5     |  cement       |   Holcim    |
```

I need to get invoice_no count of a day to "Items sold :" in my jasper report. I tried this query for my report,

```
SELECT COUNT(invoice_no) FROM normal_bill AS in_count
```

then i create a field name `$F{in_count}` to get data from query. But it not worked. Report not created. 
Can i use aliases in jasper,ireport?

if can't how to get invoice_no count to a field?   Please help me to solve my problem.

**Please close this question: This is a application error. I tried this query using older version of ireport and worked fine**

Comment: Hi Four Squares, welcome to SO.

Comment: SO is the StackOverflow :)

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much

Comment: Since fabio-fantoni is a correct query if this is not working you can have different problems from not correct class definition on field, not correct datasource (test it), not correct layout in report... You need to post the jrxml you are using.. that way we can see what is wrong, also if you see some errors add them. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35308715/edit) your question  and create a [mcve]

Comment: I'm very sorry. it's a application error. I tried using older version of ireport and worked fine.

Comment: Np, I will vote to close as TYPO, have fun and thanks for commenting back and not abandoning post

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a datasource like this:

```
invoice_no    main_category    sub_category
         1                A              A1
         2                A              A2
         3                B              B1
```

and assuming that you want to show the total count of invoice, you should just use a query (with alias using as) like this:

```
select count(invoice_no) as in_count
  from your_table
```

then, in iReport you just need to use a text field and "put inside it":

```
$F{in_count}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but please read the question. That's what i did before. i used a text field like $F{in_count}

Comment: can you add some more details? maybe a screenshot... maybe it's just me, but I'm not getting your point... are you running the report "inside" iReport editor?

Comment: is your datasource selected when you run the report, or are you accidentally running the report with "empty datasource"?

Comment: Yes.i tried with the correct datasource several times.

Comment: could you please add some screenshot of your design and what are you getting in iReport?

Answer (score 0):

Do change your query as below

```
SELECT COUNT(invoice_no) AS total_invoices FROM normal_bill
```

so alias total_invoices will return the number of invoices from database.

Comment: I tried that,but still report is not generating...

Comment: could you please be more specific? can you add what is not generating?

Comment: Copy this query and try to execute it directly into the database. It should return you some count. Don't know how are you are using it in your code.

Comment: I already tired executing in database. It was succeed. but when i'm using this query in ireport, report is not generating.

Comment: is it a ireport version error? i'm using 5.1

Comment: I am not much familiar with ireport but generally this query should work with php

Comment: The field name is $F{in_count} hence AS in_count, your query works, but that is not enough to display the result in a jasper reports.. You have connection settings, field declarations, report structure ecc.